# Creating Dynamical/changeble Menuitems in C# console application using delegates?

Tags: c#, dynamic, menu, delegates

I have trouble figuring out how to use delegates to make MenuLabel dynamical , so if
user chooses shortcut "c" to change the amount of players , then it should actually change the amount of players displayed in the Menu not only in the GameEngine class.

Maybe someone could help me explain how to change my code using delegates so it actually would change the displayed Menu in the console as well.
**Menuitem class**

```
public class Menuitem
{
    public string Shortcut { get; set; } = default!;
    public string MenuLabel { get; set; } = null;
    public Func<string?>? MethodToRun { get; set; } = null;
    public Func<string?>? SubMethodToRun { get; set; } = null;
   
}
```

**Program class**

```
var game = new GameEngine(2); //default is 2 players


var startNewGameMenu = new Menu("New Game" , new List<Menuitem>()
{
    new Menuitem()
    {
        Shortcut = "c",
        MenuLabel = "Player count: " + game.Players.Count,
        MethodToRun = game.SetPlayersCount,
        //MenuLabel = game.MenulabelToString("lalalla" + game.addPlayers() ),
        
    },
    new Menuitem()
    {
        Shortcut = "t",
        MenuLabel = "Player names and types",
    },
    
    new Menuitem()
    {
        Shortcut = "s",
        MenuLabel = "Start the game",
        MethodToRun = null
        
    },
    
    
});

var mainMenu = new Menu("CARD GAME" , new List<Menuitem>()
{
    new Menuitem()
    {
        Shortcut = "n",
        MenuLabel = "New Game",
        MethodToRun = startNewGameMenu.Run
    },
    new Menuitem()
    {
        Shortcut = "l",
        MenuLabel = "Load game",
    },
    new Menuitem()
    {
        Shortcut = "o",
        MenuLabel = "Options",
    },
    
    
});
```

**Method SetPlayersCount in GameEngine**

```
public string? SetPlayersCount()
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("How many players?");
        var x = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        int j = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        Players = new List<Player>();
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) 
        {
            Players.Add(new Player()); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("New amount of players is:" + Players.Count);
        return "New amount of players is: " + Players.Count;
    }
```

## **Menu class**

```
public class Menu
{
    private string? Title { get; set; } = default!;
    private Dictionary<string, Menuitem> MenuItems { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Menuitem>();
    
    private static readonly string[] ReservedShortcuts = new string[]{"x", "b"};
    
    private const string separatorstring = "====================";

    public Menu(string? title, List<Menuitem> menuItems)
    {
        Title = title;
        foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
        {
            if (ReservedShortcuts.Contains(menuItem.Shortcut.ToLower()))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Menu shortcut '{menuItem.Shortcut.ToLower()}' is not allowed list!");
            }
            
            if (MenuItems.ContainsKey(menuItem.Shortcut.ToLower()))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Menu shortcut '{menuItem.Shortcut.ToLower()}' is already registred!");
            }
            
            MenuItems[menuItem.Shortcut.ToLower()] = menuItem;
        }
        
        
        

    }

    
    private void Draw()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Title); ;
            Console.WriteLine(separatorstring);
        }
        
        foreach (var menuItem in MenuItems)
        {
            Console.Write(menuItem.Key);
            Console.Write(")  ");
            Console.WriteLine(menuItem.Value.MenuLabel);
        }
        //should not be on main level
        Console.WriteLine("b) Back");
        
        Console.WriteLine("x) exit");
        
        
        Console.WriteLine(separatorstring);
        Console.Write("Your choice:");
    }

    public string Run()
    {
        //Console.Clear();
        
        var userChoice = "";
        do
        {
            Draw(); 
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();

            if (MenuItems.ContainsKey(userChoice?.ToLower()))
            {
                if (MenuItems[userChoice!.ToLower()].MethodToRun != null)
                {
                    var result = MenuItems[userChoice?.ToLower()].MethodToRun!();
                    if (result?.ToLower() == "x")
                    {
                        userChoice = "x";
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(!ReservedShortcuts.Contains(userChoice?.ToLower()))
            {
                Console.Write("undefined shortcut");
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine();
        } while (!ReservedShortcuts.Contains(userChoice));

        return userChoice;
        
        
    }
}
```

I tried making MenuLabel as a func/delegate(not fixed string) but i did not know how to actually implement it correctly so it would actually change the displayed Menu.

I made SetPlayersCount method to GameEngine and tried it to make it return a string that would be the new MenuLabel but it did not work as planned so my brain exploded finally since Im new to C# and delegates.

Comment: `Function<string> MenuLabel` then printing `Console.WriteLine(menuItem.Value.MenuLabel());` and setting like `MenuLabel = () => "string"`  (simple) or with `MenuLabel = () => "string" + whatever.count `(with data)

Comment: Thank you , it works but im trying to understand why it works.                      
MenuLabel = () => "string" + whatever.count  , so what is really happening here? you are assigning MenuLabel function a return result here?

Comment: For second question  from comment the answer is yes... Instead string property which you are only assign when you are creating instance you have Func<string> which would evaluate results every time when it is called [Would You Like to Know More?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)